# change colour of gridview cell without change header color

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to change colour of my gridview row conditionaly without change header colour

here is my databound function

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime Kbl = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "HrsKbl"));

        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (Kbl == DateTime.Now)
            {
                cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            if (Kbl > DateTime.Now)
            {
                cell.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            if (Kbl < DateTime.Now)
            {
                cell.Backcolor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="Katalog" CssClass="myGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanging="exportGrdVw_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="alt" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Font-Italic="True" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID Pinjam" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("IDPinjam") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Font-Italic="True" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Katalog" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelKatalog" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Katalog") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Font-Italic="True" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kbl" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true" Visible="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelKbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("HrsKbl") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Font-Italic="True" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Font-Italic="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEdit" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" Text="Kembalikan" OnClick="LinkEdit_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Font-Italic="True" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
<EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
<PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
<SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
<EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
```

when i run it, header of my gridview always change its colour to "red" too just like the third condition of my row databound

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the if will check if it is actually a row and no the header, footer, etc

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    DateTime Kbl = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "HrsKbl"));

    foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
    {
        if (Kbl == DateTime.Now)
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        if (Kbl > DateTime.Now)
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        if (Kbl < DateTime.Now)
        {
            cell.Backcolor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider in addition to Enrique's answer:

1. Each call to `DateTime.Now` creates and returns a DateTime structure populated with the current time.  This happens so fast that with only a few lines in the grid you likely won't see a difference.  But the longer the list the more likely you will see "drift" such that `DateTime.Now` in row 1 won't match the time of `DateTime.Now` in row N
2. If you are trying to change the color of each row there is a far easier way to do that than a cell at a time.

Try doing this instead:

```
DateTime timestamp;

protected void OnDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timestamp = DateTime.Now ;
}

protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    DateTime Kbl = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "HrsKbl"));

    e.Row.BackColor = (Kbl == timestamp ? Color.Yellow : 
                      (Kbl > timestamp ? Color.Green : Color:Red));
  }
}
```